# Wordpress, doesnt send mails

Tags: wordpress, email, server, smtp, contact-form-7

I have installed wordpress on a server from one.com. I have make a contact from with the plugin 'contact form 7'. When i completed the form on the website, wordpress send the data to the url like this:

*http://damario.nl/reserveren/?_wpcf7=52&_wpcf7_version=4.1&_wpcf7_locale=nl_NL&_wpcf7_unit_tag=wpcf7-f52-o1&_wpnonce=8f673bb18f&your-name=Nicky+teest&your-email=info%40nickywiesbrock.nl&your-subject=test&your-message=03216dewf*

I recieve no mail on the mail that i have have autorized. Also i have tested an other plugin to make a contact form but it have the same isue.

Can anybody help me?

**EDIT**

See here my configrution of the WP-SMTP-MAIL and Contact form 7

[WP-SMTP MAIL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Kpk3.png)

[Contact form 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuYIo.png)

**WITH THE EASY WP SMTP PLUGIN**

[Contact form 7 (a new one)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zap48.png)

[EASY WP SMTP settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxAUb.png)

**THE CONTACT FORM SEND DATA TO URL**

[CONTACT FROM SEND DATA TO URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZzxo.png)

Comment: You probably need to set up the sendmail on your server etc. The easiest way to do this would be to install proper WP plugin that would setup your email for you.

Comment: @AgataCieplik a plugin like WP-SMTP-MAIL?

Comment: yup, this could do the trick ;)

Answer (score 1):

SMTP is not configured properly, I guess

1. try to get SMTP configuration from your provider (one.com)
2. install [this plugin](https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/)
3. configure the plugin and use the function to send sample email till you set all the SMTP configuration as your provider told you
4. try again your contact form

Comment: Thanks for youre reaction. This plugin works fine and i recieved the testmail. But the contact form still doesnt work. A password request works also fine.

Comment: @NickyWiesbrock, then it's a problem of Contact Form configuration, share in your question the configuration of your contact form

Comment: @NickyWiesbrock in the "Naar" field of the contact form configuration set "wordpress@damario.nl" instead of "info@damario.nl"

Comment: try [this SMTP plugin](https://wp-ecommerce.net/easy-wordpress-smtp-send-emails-from-your-wordpress-site-using-a-smtp-server-2197) instead of WP-SMTP mail. And after you configure it, create a new contact form and try the new one

Comment: The test mail works! but the contact form doesn't, see printscreen

Comment: @NickyWiesbrock, can't see any print screen, sorry

Comment: The contact form send the data to the url, but then it seems that te procedure stops.

Comment: @NickyWiesbrock, are you using the last version of Contact Form 7? or is it an old one? also wordpress is up-to-date?

Comment: yes i use the latest version of contact form 7 now, and i also use the latest version of wordpress

Comment: if you send a message with the contact form, do you seen a "success" message after the submit?

Comment: no, i see that the data from the form are posted to the url of the page.

Comment: @NickyWiesbrock, did you manage to solve the issue? I just saw from your site link that it should work (maybe there where some javascript errors I thought this weekend, but from mobile I couldn't check)